# Python newbie can't seem to properly subclass a PyQt4 widget

Tags: python, pyqt4

I'm a Python newbie that can't seem to properly subclass a widget in PyQt4. Initially I've created a QDockWidget object and added it to a MainWindow as follows:

```
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt3.QtGui import *

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self, parent=NONE):
        toolWindow1 = QDockWidget("Tool Window 1", self)
        self.addDockWidget(Qt.LeftDockWidgetArea, toolWindow1)
```

That worked fine. Now, I'd like to subclass QDockWidget. I create a new file called "ToolWindows.py" and add the following class to it:

```
from PyQt.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *

class BasicToolWindow(QDockWidget):

    def __init__(self, parent=NONE):
        super(BasicToolWindow, self).__init__(parent)
```

Then I try to create it in the MainWindow as follows:

```
toolWindow1 = BasicToolWindow("Tool Window 1", self)
```

This causes the following error at runtime: "**init**() takes at most 2 arguments (3 given)". Can someone please explain what I've done wrong here, and can someone also point me to a good explanation of subclassing online? I haven't been successful in finding one myself. Thank you!

Comment: Add a `title` argument to `__init__`, and pass it on to the base-class.

Comment: Thanks ekhumoro. I actually tried that initially but just couldn't get the syntax right. What is the correct syntax? I think what's throwing me off is the "parent" argument...I don't really get that at the moment.

Comment: I have added an answer to explain it further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def __init__(self, parent=NONE):
```

it just has 2 arguments. Also, when you do

```
toolWindow1 = BasicToolWindow("Tool Window 1", self)
```

it will give "self" implicitly to the argument. So what you have left is just the parent argument that you have filled with "Tool Window 1."

Basically, you gave BasicToolWindow three arguments: self, "Tool Window 1", and self. That's why the compiler wasn't happy.

Answer (score 1):

The [QDockWidget](https://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qdockwidget.html#public-functions) class has two constructors. One takes a *title*, *parent* and *flags*, whilst the other takes only a *parent* and *flags*. If you want to use these arguments when creating an instance of your `BasicToolWindow` subclass, you need to define them in the signature of its `__init__`:

```
class BasicToolWindow(QDockWidget):
    def __init__(self, title, parent=None):
```

The *parent* argument is optional in the `QDockWidget` C++ constructor and defaults to `NULL` (i.e. no parent) - so the PyQt equivalent of `parent=None` is added to match this. The *flags* argument is omitted because it is very rarely needed, and Qt already provides a default value.

These arguments then need to be passed on to the base-class `__init__` via `super` so that the `QDockWidget` constructor gets the arguments it expects:

```
class BasicToolWindow(QDockWidget):
    def __init__(self, title, parent=None):
        super(BasicToolWindow, self).__init__(title, parent)
```

Now when you create the `BasicToolWindow`, the underlying dock-widget's title is set, and the main-window (i.e. `self`) becomes its parent:

```
toolWindow1 = BasicToolWindow("Tool Window 1", self)
```